# Code compiles fine in both VS and in UE4, can't package the game,

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have no idea where to post my question to get help.. I'm freaking desperate at this point..
I have Visual Studio Community 2019 set to Shipping, I'm also packaging in Shipping in UE4. When I build the project in VS19 it compiles successfully, and also when I compile in UE4 it compiles fine. In the VC++ section in project properties in VS, I have all the needed include folders set up already. After all of this, packaging fails when I try to package to Windows 64bit. It only reports one "Unknown Error" but I've noticed it's not finding the include files. The picture shows the relevant log section:

[image]

I hope and wish someone could help! And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally SOLVED!

I had to include the full path to the file in each #include line.

Example: #include "Mayhaemsters/Actors/C_PickupItem.h"